# Checking Sort of String Array: Output doesn't match expected

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to create this program to check the sort of a list of words to see whether they are in ascending, or descending order. I am copying the words from a file to an array of strings. I am told the regular comparison operators function the same with strings as they do with ints. However, when I run the program, it always outputs that the list is unordered (even when it is). I would greatly appreciate any help one could offer me. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int checkArraySort(int array_max, string arr[]);

int main(void)
{
const int array_max = 20;
string arr[array_max];
int d;

ifstream myfile_in;
myfile_in.open ("words_in.txt");

string line;

for(int i = 0; i < array_max; i++)
{
    getline(myfile_in, line);
}

d = checkArraySort(array_max, arr);

if(d == -1)
{
    cout << "The array is sorted in descending order!" << endl;
}

if(d == 0)
{
    cout << "The array is not sorted!" << endl;
}

if(d == 1)
{
    cout << "The array is sorted in ascending order!" << endl;
}

myfile_in.close();
return 0;
}

int checkArraySort(int array_max, string arr[])
{   
bool y = false;
int j = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array_max; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] < arr[i-1])
    {
        j++;
    }

    if(j == (array_max))
    {
        y = true;
        return -1;
    }
}

j = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array_max; i++)
{

    if(arr[i] > arr[i-1])
    {
        j++;
    }

    if(j == (array_max))
    {
        y = true;
        return 1;
    }
}

if(y = false)
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: change y=false to y==false and btw that condition is always true according to your code

Comment: `y` is unnecessary as you only set it before you `return`, so no code ever sees the change.

Comment: And with your `getline` loop you are just overwriting `line` each time.

Comment: And you never put anything in `arr`.

Comment: I had `stringstream(line) >> arr[i]` but whenever i set `arr[i] = line` in any way shape or form, i get a monstrous error :/

Comment: You start at `i = 0` and then compare `arr[i] < arr[i-1]`. Accessing an array at index -1 is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have made the changes you suggested, but I'm still having trouble inserting the strings read from the file into the array. Any suggestions on what to use to accomplish this?

Comment: @CalebMoriarty use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an old C-array and `push_back` into it.

Comment: I would, but I haven't been taught how to use vectors yet haha. Everyone seems to say they are the way to go instead of arrays, but as of right now, arrays are all I'm capable of utilizing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(y = false)
```

should be

```
if(y == false)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That still didn't fix the issue though :( I am using a file that contains a-t on separate lines hoping to get it to return that its in ascending order, but no luck.